# Retrieve the value of multiple identifiers in DataProvider

Tags: api-platform.com

I have an entity with two id's, I want to create a DataProvider and the id is `/periods/firstOperation=2021-11-13T15:38:57+00:00;lastOperation=2021-11-13T15:38:57+00:00`
How to properly extract these values contained in the id? I imagine there must be a utility but I can't find it.